# Image on HTML signature not showing up

Tags: html, outlook, signature

I have created a html signature for outlook.  When I compose a new message my images show up but once the email has been received the images don’t appear.  I was wondering if I am referencing the images correctly, they are stored in my

C: AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\signature_files    (as created by outlook).

I am finding the images like `<img src=" signature_files/image002.jpg">`

Am I referencing them wrong, should I be putting something else in my html inplace of this?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You can upload images to any web server and add links to them, so they will be downloaded on any PC. Also you can embedd them into the email.

To add an embedded image (not just a reference or link) you need to add the image as an attachment (MailItem.Attachments.Add) and set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID  property (DASL name http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F) using Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty. Then in the HTML body you can add the following markup:

```
 "<img src='cid:pictest.jpg'/>
```

Don't forget to change the picture name in the img attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do - to make sure outlook displays your signature correctly - is after putting the html file in the Signatures, right click on it and select Edit, and this should open up microsoft word. If the images aren't there, insert them and then save it. This is because Outlook uses Word's hmtl rendering engine to display html. If that doesn't open Word, right click > open with > microsoft word

Also remember you have to have three types of files for a signature to work correctly in Outlook. The HTML file, the rich text file, and the plain text file. You can create all these by using Save As in word. They have to all have the same name. So if you signature is called abc, you would end up with three files, `abc.html`, `abc.txt` and `abc.rtf`. Also a folder called `abc_files`, which is where Word stores your images, but it has to store them itself to work properly - I think...